# Gnuplot: variable linecolor for 3D-Vector plots

Tags: gnuplot

In 2D plots, it is no problem to use 4th column for supplying coloring of arrows in a vector-style plot:

```
set parametric
set trange [0:2*pi]
plot '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(0):(1):($1) w vectors lc palette
```

works as expected. However, if I pass to 3D-plots,

```
splot '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(0):(0):(1):(0):($1) w vectors lc palette
```

yields only black arrows, although the colorbox shows a realistic cbrange. Other colored 3D-plots such as

```
splot '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(0):(sprintf("%.2f", $1)):($1) w labels tc palette
```

also work as expected.

**Question:** Why is this?

*Gnuplot version: 5.0 patchlevel 3.

Comment: `splot '+' using (cos($1)):(sin($1)):(0):(0):(1):(0):($1) w vectors lc palette` seems to work fine in gnuplot 5.2.2. Maybe time to upgrade?

Comment: @user8153 yeah, at least it helped; thanks.